# PHP: retrieve multiples arrays using AND not OR

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-intersect

I use facebook graph api to retrieve my facebook posts and display them on my website.

So far I have filtered my post by tags using this code (this code retrieves the FB posts tagged with -fr- / others post are tagged with -en- : which allow me to sort my post by languages)

```
      $string = $post['message'];
      $array = array("-fr-");
      if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array)))
```

**First question:** 
I am trying now to retrieve my post based on my language tags PLUS on one another tags.

I have tied:

```
$array = array("-fr-", "#science");
```

But all the posts containing EITHER `-fr-` OR `#science` are display. What I want is to display all the post containing the tags `-fr-` AND `#science`.

**Second question:**
I would also need to retrieve posts with optional tags. For example I have those posts with these tags:

```
Post 1= -fr- #science #education
Post 2= -fr- #science #politics
Post 3= -fr- #science #animals
```

I would like to retrieve only post 1 and 2.

So `-fr-` and `#science` would be mandatory but `#education` and `#politics` would be a "EITHER... OR..." request (this request would be like:  `array("#education", "#politics"); )`

Any idea how to do it? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For your first question: why don't you run the same algorithm successively for each tag, filtering the resulting array at each step?

Comment: Well thanks a lot you're a genius Sergiu! I just added a `$array1 = array("#science");
      if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array1)))` just below the first algorithm and... it's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv By the way your trick also answered my second question: `$array3 = array("#education", "#politics");`! Please post it as an answer, I am very gratefull to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd extract that algorithm in a function:

```
$string = $post['message'];
$data = array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string));

$tag = '-fr-';

function filterByTag($data, $tags) {
    return array_intersect($data, $tags);
}

$filteredData = filterByTag($data, array('-fr'));
// AND
$filteredData = filterByTag($filteredData, array('#science'));
```

Calling it successively results in an `AND` condition.
Calling it with multiple array values in the `$tags` parameter would be an `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution (works in PHP 5.3+):

```
function filterMessages($a_messages, $a_mandatory, $a_options) {
    return array_filter($a_messages, function ($text) use ($a_mandatory, $a_options) {
        $text = " $text ";
        $fn = function ($v) use ($text) {
            return stripos($text, " $v ") !== false;
        };
        return
            count(array_filter($a_mandatory, $fn)) == count($a_mandatory) &&
            count(array_filter($a_options, $fn)) > 0;
    });
}

$a_messages = array(
'-fr- #science #education',
'-fr- #science #politics',
'-fr- #science #animals',
);
$a_mandatory = array('-fr-', '#science');
$a_options = array('#education', '#politics');
print_r(filterMessages($a_messages, $a_mandatory, $a_options));
```

Comment: Thanks Hindmost! Would `if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array)))` not work with PHP above 5.3 ?(I am using 5.3.16 and it's still working)